Unable to remove a PPA I installed when I had an older version of Ubuntu
I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 from an older version (16? 18? I forget)
I have a tablet, and apparently I acquired the tablet drivers from a third party PPA
ppa:doctormo/wacom-plus
Well, now that I've upgraded to 22.04, the tablet's stylus often fails to function. Reading about the PPA, it hasn't been updated in years- it's not meant to be compatible with 22.04.
I need to remove the old PPA and install something appropriate for 22.04. Someone recommended I use opentabletdriver.
So ... how do I remove the old PPA?
I've tried
sudo ppa-purge pp:doctormo/wacom-plus

but that just returns this message:
Updating packages lists
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/doctormo/wacom-plus/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason

I'm not super Linux savvy, so I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.
Thanks for any help you have to offer!

to remove the ppa all you need to do is this
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/PPA_Name.list

then install xserver-xorg-input-wacom
for a gui install OpenTabletDriver
wget
https://github.com/OpenTabletDriver/OpenTabletDriver/releases/latest/download/OpenTabletDriver.deb
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ./OpenTabletDriver.deb
systemctl --user enable opentabletdriver.service --now

Hi! Thanks for your help!
The old PPA is gone.
As for installing the openTabletDriver, I was able to run all the commands you provided except the first one.
$ install xserver-xorg-input-wacom
install: missing destination file operand after 'xserver-xorg-input-wacom'
Try 'install --help' for more information.
Should my tablet become usable after running the systemctl command? It's not responding.

@TwirlySocrates you forgot the sudo apt for that command

I see, thanks for pointing that out. I got that GUI to install.
My tablet still isn't working, however. I never thought to check that openTabletDriver is actually compatible with my tablet (Wacom DTK-2200), and it's not on the list.
https://opentabletdriver.net/Tablets
I should remove that opentabletdriver, shouldn't I?
I still need a driver though- is there a standard place to look for those sorts of things? In the past I've just been installing whatever people like yourself tell me to do, but I don't know where they find this stuff.

I should add: my wacom isn't being detected at all. With my old driver, it used to be that I could run lsusb, and it would show up. Now there's nothing.
